# how to get data with relation in Laravel trying to get Bill Products to view

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 models connected together Vendors has many Bills and bills has many bill_products

what do I need is to display the data with this relation in the index view here is my controller index function

```
    public function index()
    {
        $vendor = $this->vendor();
        $data['vendor_id'] = $vendor->id;
        $data['bills'] = $vendor->bills()->get();
        return view('vendors.bills.index', $data);
    }
```

this bills relation in vendor model

```
   public function bills()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(VendorBill::class);
    }
```

Vendor bills model where I put my relation to bill products

```
class VendorBill extends Model
{
    const FILLABLE = [
        'making_cost',
        'gram_price',
        'customer_name',
        'customer_id',
        'vendor_id',
        'id_no',
        'phone',
        'bill_no',
        'total',
    ];
    protected $fillable = self::FILLABLE;

    public function vendor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Vendor::class);
    }
    public function billProducts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(VendorBillProduct::class);
    }
}
```

and this is the last Model that belongs to Vendor Bills where i need to get data from

```
class VendorBillProduct extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = "bill_products";

    const FILLABLE = [
        'vendor_bill_id',
        'cate_code',
        'product_description',
        'metal_weight',
        'total_metal_weight',
        'caliber',
        'gem_stone_weight',
        'diamond_weight',
        'purity',
        'color',
        'dimond',
    ];
    protected $fillable = self::FILLABLE;

    public function vendorBill()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(VendorBill::class);
    }
}
```

this is the index blade view where I want to get data stored in BillProducts the belongs to the VendorBill

```xml
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">@lang('vendors.bill_no')</th>
                <th scope="col">@lang('vendors.customer')</th>
                <th scope="col">@lang('vendors.phone')</th>
                <th scope="col">@lang('vendors.cate_code')</th>
                <th class="text-right" scope="col">@lang('vendors.action')</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if($bills->count())
                @foreach(@$bills as $bill)
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">{{@$bill->bill_no}}</th>
                        <th scope="row">{{@$bill->customer_name}}</th>
                        <td>{{@$bill->phone}}</td>
                        <td>{{@$bill->cate_code}}</td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-light tn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <i class="fal fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                    <a href="{{route('vendors.bills.edit',$bill->id)}}" class="dropdown-item" type="button">
                                        @lang('vendors.edit')
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('vendors.bills.show',$bill->id)}}">@lang('vendors.details')</a>
                                    {{--<button class="dropdown-item" type="button">
                                        @lang('vendors.delete')
                                    </button>--}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            @endif
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqi3B.png)

in this image, I highlighted the column that I need to get in relation

Comment: Since it's a HasMany relationship you'd need to do something like `$bill->billProducts->pluck('cate_code')->join(', ')` to get all the codes in one line.

Comment: But there can be multiple codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a clever solution within your problem. Create a method on your `VendorBill.php` model, that concats the codes.

```
class VendorBill
{
    function concatCodes(): string
    {
        return $this->billProducts->pluck('cate_code')->implode(', ');
    }
}
```

Now in the context of a bill, you can convert all its vendor bills into that string and then implode that.

```
$bill->map->concatCodes()->implode(', ');
```

This will then concat the codes into the a string similar to this

```
code1, code2, code3
```